# position: sticky doesn't work when wrapped in div

Tags: html, css

When I wrap `<div class="sticky">Title</div>` into another `<div></div>` it doesn't work anymore. Why? And how can I make it work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .sticky {
                top: 0;
                position: sticky;
                position: -webkit-sticky;
            }

            p {
                line-height: 150px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="sticky">Title</div>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it's because of the div go to the top:0; of his parent. So first it's body and adding a div it become the div.. ?

Comment: Sounds plausible, how could I make it work?

Comment: What do you want ? Can you add a fiddle with the problem ?